# ravendb count query not equal tolist count

Tags: linq, count, ravendb

ravendb query return different result for count method and tolist().count

query 1(return 9):

```
var count = session.Query<MobileForm,ByFormNameIndex>().Where(x => x.RequestType == RequestType.Db && x.BelongTo == oaname).ToList().Count;
```

query 2(return 44):

```
var count = session.Query<MobileForm,ByFormNameIndex>().Where(x => x.RequestType == RequestType.Db && x.BelongTo == oaname).Count();
```

index define:

```
public class ByFormNameIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MobileForm>
{
     public ByFormNameIndex()
    {

    Map = mobileForms => from form in mobileForms
                         select new
                         {
                             form.FormName,
                             form.BelongTo,
                             form.RequestType,
                             form.CreateTime,
                             form.Uuid
                         };
    Analyzers.Add(x => x.FormName, "Lucene.Net.Analysis.PanGu.PanGuAnalyzer,PanGu.Lucene.Analyzer, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
    Indexes.Add(x => x.FormName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    Indexes.Add(x => x.BelongTo, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    Indexes.Add(x => x.RequestType, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
    Indexes.Add(x => x.Uuid, FieldIndexing.NotAnalyzed);
}
```

}

query1 return the right count, so what's the differrent for this to method?show i new to rebuild the index to get the right result?

Comment: Can you provide a failing test? ravendb.net/docs/samples/raven-tests/createraventests

Answer (score 1):

That is by design.
`Count()` will give you the total count.
`ToList()` gives you the first page only. And then you get the count on that.

Comment: the default pagesize is 9? i think tolist should take more than this .